# Testing Resposive Screens | Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hi friends just testing out responsiveness of my website.

So i made a basic code, hoping titles in the pages will be made responsive for different screen size.

here is the HTML code,

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Testing Responsive Screens</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class='divHeader'><!-- Contact Us title Start -->

    <div class="container"><!--container-->

        <div class="row"><!-- Contact Us title -->

            <!-- LARGE SCREEN TITLE -->

            <div class='LGS'>

                <div class='col-lg-4'></div>

                <div class='col-lg-4 divHeaderContent text-center'>
                    <h1><br>Contact Us</h1>
                </div>

                <div class='col-lg-4'></div>

            </div>

            <!-- MEDIUM SCREEN TITLE -->

            <div class='MDS'>

                <div class='col-md-4'></div>

                <div class='col-md-4 divHeaderContent text-center'>
                    <h2><br>Contact Us</h2>
                </div>

                <div class='col-md-4'></div>

            </div>

            <!-- SMALL SCREEN TITLE -->

            <div class='SMS'>

                <div class='col-sm-4'></div>

                <div class='col-sm-4 divHeaderContent text-center'>
                    <h3><br>Contact Us</h3>
                </div>

                <div class='col-sm-4'></div>

            </div>

            <!-- EXTRA SMALL 1 SCREEN TITLE -->

            <div class="XSS1">

                <div class='col-xs-4'></div>

                <div class='col-xs-4 divHeaderContent text-center'>
                    <h4><br>Contact Us</h4>
                </div>

                <div class='col-xs-4'></div>

            </div>

            <!-- EXTRA SMALL 2 SCREEN TITLE -->

            <div class="XSS2">

                <div class='col-xs-4'></div>

                <div class='col-xs-4 divHeaderContent text-center'>
                    <h6><br>Contact Us</h6>
                </div>

                <div class='col-xs-4'></div>

            </div>

        </div><!-- End of Contact Us title -->

    </div><!--End of container-->

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

& the simple CSS,

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /* ================== GENERAL RULE ===================== */
    .MDS, .SMS, .XSS1, .XSS2{
        display: none;    
    }
}

     /* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
      @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        /* ================== GENERAL RULE ===================== */
        .LGS, .SMS, .XSS1, .XSS2{
            display: none;    
        }
     }

     /* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
     @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        /* ================== GENERAL RULE ===================== */
        .LGS, .MDS, .XSS1, .XSS2{
            display: none;    
        }
     }

     /* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
     @media (max-width: 767px) {
        /* ================== GENERAL RULE ===================== */
        .LGS, .MDS, .SMS, .XSS2{
            display: none;    
        }
     }

     /* Portrait phones and smaller */
     @media (max-width: 480px) {
        /* ================== GENERAL RULE ===================== */
        .LGS, .MDS, .SMS, .XSS1{
            display: none;    
        }
     }
```

Classes are dedicated to each type screen size.

Problem occurs in the smallest screen size. The title simply doesn't appears. Help me people, let me know here I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not specify a min width for `Landscape phones and portrait tablets`. So at 767px and less XSS2 is hidden anyway (even in 'Portrait phones and smaller' case). There is a fix:

```
/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* ================== GENERAL RULE ===================== */
     .LGS, .MDS, .SMS, .XSS2{
        display: none;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/LZVyPQ , it's a little easier to follow what's happening at the different viewports if you hide all your custom classes, then specify **which to displa**y for each breakpoint, as opposed to specifying **which to hide** at each breakpoint.

```
 .LGS, .MDS, .SMS,.XSS1, .XSS2{display:none;}

 @media (max-width: 480px) {
   .XSS2{
     display:block;
   }
}

 @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   .XSS1{
     display:block;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
   .SMS{
     display:block;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .MDS{
     display:block;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .LGS{
     display:block;
   }
}
```

In case you don't know, Bootstrap does have native responsive utilities which can achieve some of what you are looking for: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Also it's not clear from your code if you've include a [viewport meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) in the head of your doc, if not you need something like

```
<head>  
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```

Good luck!